# .ajax call doesn't work when called during select_node.jstree event for non-leaf nodes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

When calling $.ajax, it returns information just fine when the select_node.jstree event is fired unless its for a non-leaf node.  In that case, the server receives the ajax call and returns the data but for some reason the success function is never called.  Here is the code:

```
$("#demo1").jstree({ "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui"] })
   .bind("select_node.jstree",
     function(event, data1) {
       var agentId = data1.rslt.obj.attr("id");
       $.ajax({
         url: '@Url.Action("GetAgentInfo", "Home")',
         dataType: 'json',
         type: 'POST',
         data: { id: agentId },
         success: function(msg) {
           $("#agentDisplay").html("Agent Name:" + msg.LastName + ", " + msg.FirstName);
         },
         failure: function() { alert('error'); }
       });
     });
  });
```

The HTML looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li id="1"> <a href="#">Parent 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li id="11"> <a href="#">Child 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li id="1026"> <a href="#">Leaf 1</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="1013"> <a href="#">Leaf 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li id="1021"> <a href="#">Leaf 3</a>    
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Leaf 1, 2 and 3 return info just fine.  Parent 1 and child 1 hit the server method and return data but the success method isn't called.

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm sure its something stupid I'm overlooking.

Comment: in console did u get any error from post call?? and how are u returning data json encoded??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using jstree recently and I rant into a similar issue where I was not able to bind events to my tree.  The only way I could get it working is by binding first and then using jstree.  Here is how your code would look:

```
jQuery("#demo1")
   .bind("select_node.jstree",
   function(event, data1) {
   var agentId = data1.rslt.obj.attr("id");
   $.ajax({
             url: '@Url.Action("GetAgentInfo", "Home")',
             dataType: 'json',
             type: 'POST',
             data: { id: agentId },
             success: function(msg) {
             $("#agentDisplay").html("Agent Name:" + msg.LastName + ", " + msg.FirstName);
                         },
                        failure: function() { alert('error'); }
                    });
                });
    })
.jstree({ "plugins": ["themes", "html_data", "ui"] });
```